# How can I construct a Dynamic Enum in scala

Tags: scala, generics

How can I construct a Dynamic EnumCreator in Scala?

```
class EnumCreater{
  def create[T <: Enum[_]](clazz :Class[T],input:String):T = Enum.valueOf(clazz,input)
}
```

sclac compiler report:

```
error: inferred type arguments [T] do not conform to method valueOf's type parameter bounds [T <: java.lang.Enum[T]]
```

I tried asInstanceOf to workaround this issue,It doesn't work. So what shall I do?

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it compile you need to replace the `_` with `T`

```
def create[T <: Enum[T]](clazz: Class[T], input: String): T = 
  Enum.valueOf(clazz, input)
```